# How do you add rotation logic for mobile devices upon dragging on a 3d globe with D3.js and html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, canvas

I've been following the example in Learning D3.js 5 mapping to create a 3D globe and implement both zoom and rotation logic to drag the map.

Here is the specific function that will take care of both features on devices where I can use a mouse for example laptops and desktops

```
function ready(data) {
      /* Interactivity goes here */

      var zoom = d3
        .zoom()
        .scaleExtent([0.5, 4])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

      canvas.call(zoom);

      function zoomed() {
        var event = d3.event.sourceEvent.type;
        var dx = d3.event.sourceEvent.movementX;
        var dy = d3.event.sourceEvent.movementY;

        if (event === "wheel") {
          var transformScale = d3.event.transform.k;

          projectionScaleChange =
            (transformScale - prevTransformScale) * origProjectionScale;
          projectionScale = projectionScale + projectionScaleChange;
          projection.scale(projectionScale);
          prevTransformScale = transformScale;
        } else if (event === "mousemove") {
          // Here goes the rotation logic as this will be triggered upon dragging
          var r = projection.rotate();
          console.log(r);
          rotation = [r[0] + dx * 0.4, r[1] - dy * 0.5, r[2]];
          projection.rotate(rotation);
        } else {
          console.warn("unknown mouse event in zoomed()"); // alerting issues
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
          renderScene(data);
        });
      }

    }
```

The logic works great until I want to implement these functionalities on mobile devices. I tried to add a case for the touchmove event as shown below

function ready(data) {

```
  /* Interactivity goes here */

  var zoom = d3
    .zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.5, 4])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  canvas.call(zoom);

  function zoomed() {
    var event = d3.event.sourceEvent.type;
    var dx = d3.event.sourceEvent.movementX;
    var dy = d3.event.sourceEvent.movementY;

    if (event === "wheel") {
      var transformScale = d3.event.transform.k;

      projectionScaleChange =
        (transformScale - prevTransformScale) * origProjectionScale;
      projectionScale = projectionScale + projectionScaleChange;
      projection.scale(projectionScale);
      prevTransformScale = transformScale;
    } else if (event === "mousemove") {
      // Here goes the rotation logic as this will be triggered upon dragging
      var r = projection.rotate();
      rotation = [r[0] + dx * 0.4, r[1] - dy * 0.5, r[2]];
      projection.rotate(rotation);
    } else if (event === "touchmove") {
      var r = projection.rotate();
      rotation = [r[0] + dx * 0.4, r[1] - dy * 0.5, r[2]];
      projection.rotate(rotation);
    } else {
      console.warn("unknown mouse event in zoomed()"); // alerting issues
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      renderScene(data);
    });
  }

}
```

but doing so won't move the map on dragging with a mobile device. I also tried to log the values of the variable r when the eventtype = touchmove and realized the 3 values in the array don't change compared to when I log the same r variable when the eventtype = mousemove. I need to understand why. Somebody please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, touch devices don't expose the `mousemove` but rather a `touchmove` event. Once you tested for `touchmove` you also have to consider that the screen coordinates are no direct child of the event's `sourceEvent` object but properties of the event *touches* object properties.

[Here's a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/globe-dragging-desktop-mobile-vn0e5) that will let your users drag the globe on mobile. The key piece is in the `getPosition` function:

```js
function getPostions(e) {
  let x;
  let y;

  // Ringfencing, in case type is not defined.
  if (!e) return [0, 0];

  // Distinguish between desktop and touch.
  if (e.type === "mousemove") {
    x = e.screenX;
    y = e.screenY;
  } else if (e.type === "touchmove") {
    x = e.changedTouches[0].screenX;
    y = e.changedTouches[0].screenY;
  }

  return [x, y];
}
```

Depending on the `<event>.type` exposed (either `mousemove` or `touchmove`) you retrieve the screen coordinates either directly from the event object or as nested properties from the first `<event>.changedTouches` property.

However, zoom is trickier and not implemented in above example.

For a more elegant overall solution (also solving the [Gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) issue with 2D globe rotation) please see [this versor zooming](https://observablehq.com/@d3/versor-zooming) implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out that getPosition function to retrieve screen co-ordinates